# Embeddings of finite groups into GL(n,Q_p)

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, galois-theory, nt.number-theory

This question is inspired by some interesting comments on [this recent question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/128194/upper-bound-on-order-of-finite-subgroups-of-gl-nz-p).

Fix an integer $n \geq 1$ and a finite subgroup $G$ of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{C})$. It is known that there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $G$ embeds into $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{Q}_p)$. This follows from the Cassels Embedding Theorem : every finitely generated field of characteristic 0 embeds into $\mathbf{Q}_p$ for infinitely many primes $p$ (see Cassels's book *Local Fields* or Cassels's article *An embedding theorem for fields*. Bull. Austral. Math. Soc. 14 (1976), 193-198; see also Chapter 4 of [Pete L. Clark's notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/8410FULL.pdf)).

Representation theoretic arguments actually show that $G$ occurs in $\mathrm{GL}_n(\overline{\mathbf{Q}})$ and thus in $\mathrm{GL}_n(K)$ for some number field $K$. From this and Chebotarev's density theorem, we deduce that the set $S(G)$ of primes $p$ such that $G \hookrightarrow \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{Q}_p)$ has positive density.

Does the set $S(G)$ have a natural density?

Is the set $S(G)$ a Galoisian set of prime numbers in the sense of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11747/galoisian-sets-of-prime-numbers)?

Comment: I'm glad you posted the question.  I think though you should also refer the reader interested in CET to either Cassels's book *Local Fields* or to: J.W.S. Cassels, An embedding theorem for fields. Bull. Austral. Math. Soc. 14 (1976), 193-198.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$\def\Gal{\mathrm{Gal}}$
$\def\Res{\mathrm{Res}}$
$\def\GL{\mathrm{GL}}$
$\def\F{\mathbf{F}}$
$\def\Q{\mathbf{Q}}$

**Edited to include more details.**

Let $K$ be a field whose characteristic is prime to the order of $G$.
The algebra $K[G]$ is a product of matrix algebras over division rings.
Given any *absolutely irreducible* character $\chi$ with coefficients in $L/K$, the question of whether $\chi$ may be realized over $L$ is equivalent to whether the corresponding division algebra $D/K$ splits over $L$.

Suppose that $K = k$ is a finite field. Then, by Weddeburn's theorem, there are no non-trivial division algebras and irreducible characters with values in $k$ have models over $k$.

Suppose that $K$ is a number field. For all but finitely many places $v$ of $K$, $D \otimes_K K_v$ is a matrix algebra. So, at least away from finitely many places, irreducible characters with values in $K$ have models over $K_v$.

**Example:** Let $G = Q_8$ be the quaternion group, and let $\chi$ denote the absolutely irreducible faithful character of degree $2$. Then $\chi$ is valued in $\Q$. However, the corresponding quaternion algebra $D$ is ramified at $2$ and $\infty$. Hence $G$ does not have a faithful representation over either $\mathbf{R}$ nor $\mathbf{Q}_2$, but it does for $\Q_p$ and all odd primes $p$, because $D \otimes \Q_p = M_2(\Q_p)$ in those cases.

In the example above, we see that the obstruction arises for finite places only at the prime $2$ which divides $|G|$. Let us show that there is no obstruction for any $v$ such that the residue characteristic is finite and prime to $|G|$. In such cases, there is a bijection between absolutely irreducible characters in characteristics zero and $p$ given by reduction modulo $p$. Let $\chi$ be an irreducible character with values in a local field $E$. It preserves a lattice $\mathcal{O}$, and gives rise to an irreducible character over the finite field $k$, which has a model over $k$ by the remarks above. Hence (because the characters are in bijection) it suffices to prove the following: any representation:
$$G \rightarrow \GL_n(k)$$
with image $H$ admits a lift to $\GL_n(W(k))$, since $W(k)[1/p]$ will be necessarily be a subfield of $E$. (Not surprisingly, we see that all representations have models over unramified extensions when $p \nmid |G|$, since the characters are all valued in $\Q(\zeta_{m})$ where $m$ is the exponent of $G$.)
There is a projection $\GL_n(W(k)) \rightarrow \GL_n(k)$; let $\Gamma$ denote the inverse image of $H$. Since $H$ has order prime to $p$ and the kernel of $\Gamma \rightarrow H$ is pro-$p$, by Schur-Zassenhaus there is a splitting $H \rightarrow \Gamma$ which gives the required lift.

Suppose now that $\eta$ is a general (genuine) character of $G$ over a local field $K/\Q_p$ with values generate the field $L/K$, and suppose that
$p$ does not divide $|G|$. We prove that $\eta$ has a model over $L$. As noted above, $L/K$ is unramified, so in particular is Galois and $\Gal(L/K)$ is cyclic.
The result is true for 
irreducible characters from the discussion above.
Suppose that $\chi$ is an irreducible constituent of $\eta$. Since $\Gal(L/K)$ fixes $\eta$,
it follows that the $[L:K]$ distinct characters $\sigma \chi$ occur inside $\eta$.
Hence

$$\eta = \phi + \sum_{\Gal(L/K)} \sigma \chi,$$
where $\eta$ is a genuine character of lower dimension. Hence it suffices to note that
$$\bigoplus \sigma \chi$$
is defined over $K$, because if $V/L$ is a realization of $\chi$, then the above is 
$\mathrm{Res}_{L/K}(V)$,  where $L/K$ is thought of as a $[L:K]$-dimensional vector
space in the usual way. The result follows by induction.

**Example:** Suppose that $p \equiv -1 \mod 4$, and let $\chi$ be a faithful character of $\mathbf{Z}/4\mathbf{Z}$. Then $K = \Q_p(\chi)$ is unramified over $\Q_p$ of degree $2$, and the representation $\chi + \sigma \chi$ is sends a generator to $i \in K$ thought of as a vector space over $\Q_p$. If one chooses the basis $\{1,i\}$ of $K/\Q_p$, this is just the matrix:
$$\left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\\ -1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right).$$

**Conclusion:** Hence, at least for primes $p$ not dividing $|G|$, there is an injection from $G$ to $\GL_n(\Q_p)$ if and only if there is a faithful character $\eta$ with
values in a field $K$ which has a prime of norm $p$. Since $K$ will be abelian and ramified only at primes dividing $|G|$, this is equivalent to asking that $K$ split completly at $p$. So the set $S(G)$ (up to primes dividing $|G|$) is the union of primes which split completely in some finite number of fields determined by the faithful characters of degree $n$. If one restricts to a fixed character $\eta$, then $S_{\eta}(G)$ is indeed Galoisian.

Providing that $\eta$ has at least one faithful character of degree $n$, then $S(G)$ has rational positive density, answering 1. As for 2, it is not *strictly* Galoisian according to the definition of the previous question, since that required that the set be the set of primes
 which split completely in a *single* field. For example, one can take
$$G = \mathbf{Z}/12 \mathbf{Z}$$
and $n = 2$. Then $G$ is a subgroup of $\mathbf{GL}_2(\Q_p)$ for $p > 3$ if and only if  $p \equiv 1,5,7 \mod 12$, but not $11 \mod 12$, and this is not the set of primes which splits completely in any field $L$. In this case, if $\chi$ is a faithful character of $G$ of degree $1$, then $\chi + \chi^5$ and $\chi + \chi^{-1}$ are faithful characters with values in $\Q(\sqrt{-1})$  and $\Q(\sqrt{-3})$ respectively.

If $G$ has a faithful character of degree $n$ with values in $\Q$, then we see that $G$ embeds into $\GL_n(\Q_p)$ for all but finitely many primes $p$. The converse is quite possibly false, however; one could imagine $G$ having faithful characters of degree $n$ with values in $\Q(\sqrt{2})$, $\Q(\sqrt{3})$, and $\Q(\sqrt{6})$ but not in $\Q$ (although I don't have an example off the top of my head.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your nice example shows that one can refine the question by looking only at those embeddings of $G$ into $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{Q}_p)$ which are compatible with a given complex faithful character of $G$. Regarding your argument, I don't see why the existence of a faithful $\mathbf{Q}_p$-valued character implies that $G$ embeds into $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{F}_p)$. Is it where you use your result about reps over finite fields? If so then why is the reduction mod $p$ still faithful?

Comment: That's true, although one has to be a little careful by what one means by the reduction of a character mod $p$. If $\chi$ is faithful, there's a naive sense in which the reduction mod $p$ of $p \cdot \chi$ is trivial! So I re-wrote the argument in a slightly different way.


Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to explain in more details!

Answer (score 4):

The answer is yes, I think, $S(G)$ is Frobenian. (Edited: actually, as noticed by Rabelais and
the OP, there is a gap if the representation $r_i$ below are not all irreducible. I leave the argument as it still gives a positive answer in the case where all faithful rep. of $G$ of dim $n$ are irreducible -- for instance, when $G$ is non-abelian and $n=2$).

Let $(r_i)$ for $i=1,\dots,a$ the list of all faithful complex representations of $G$ of dimension $n$. Let $(\rho_{i,j})_{i,j=1,\dots,b_i}$ the set of irreducible representations appearing as a component of $r_i$. Let $K_{i,j}$ be the field of *rationality* of $\rho_{i,j}$.
There is a unique (up to $\mathbb K_{i,j}$-isomorphism) central simple algebra $D_{i,j}$
together with a map $\tilde \rho_{i,j}: G \rightarrow D_{i,j}$ which after tenderization by $\mathbb C$ gives back $\rho_{i,j}$.

> **Claim**: for a prime $p$, the two following properties are equivalent.
>   (1) $G$ can be embedded in $Gl_n(\mathbb Q_p)$
>   (2) There exists $i$ such that for all $j \in \{1,\dots,b_i\}$, there exists a prime $\mathcal P$ in $K_{i,j}$ of degree $1$ above $p$ and at which $D_{i,j}$ is split.

Proof of the claim: (2) implies (1) because if $\mathcal P$ is as in (2), $(K_{i,j})_{(\mathcal P)}=\mathbb Q_p$, and $D_{i,j} \otimes (K_{i,j})_{(\mathcal P)} = \mathbb Q_p$; thus the $\rho_{i,j}$ for that fixed $i$ are all defined over $\mathbb Q_p$, and
so is their sum over $j$, that is $r_i$, and $r_i$ being faithful defined an embedding of $G$ into $Gl_n(\mathbb Q_p)$.

Proof of (1) implies (2). If $G$ can be embedded into $Gl_n(\mathbb Q_p)$ let $r$ be the embedding, that we see as an $n$-dimensional representation over $\mathbb Q_p$. Embedding $\mathbb Q_p$ to $\mathbb C$, we see $r$ as a complex representation which is thus one of the $r_i$. So $r_i$ is defined over $\mathbb Q_p$, which means that all the $\rho_{i,j}$ are,
which in turns means that (2) holds y the lemma below. (end of proof of the claim)

---

Now it is clear that (2) defines a Frobenian set of primes.

---

Lemma: let $\rho: G \rightarrow Gl_n(\mathbb Q_p)$ be an absolutely 
irreducible representation, that we see as a complex irreducible representation
by the choice of an embedding $\mathbb Q_p \rightarrow \mathbb C$. Let $K$
be its rationality field (the subfield of $\mathbb C$ generated by the $tr \rho(g))$, so that there exists a central simple algebra $D/K$ of rank $n^2$ such that
$\rho$ comes from a "representation" $\tilde \rho: G \rightarrow D^\ast$. Then
there is a place $\mathcal P$ of $K$ such that the completion $K_{\mathcal P}$ is $\mathbb Q_p$, and $D \otimes_K K_{\mathcal P} = M_n(K_{\mathcal P})$.

Proof: Since $K$ is generated (as a field over $\mathbb Q$) by the $tr \rho(g)$, and the $tr \rho(g)$ are in $\mathbb Q_p$, one has $K \subset \mathbb Q_p$. Let us take for $\mathcal P$ the prime
corresponding to the restriction of the standard absolute value on $\mathbb Q_p$ to $K$.
Then clearly $K_{\mathcal P} = \mathbb Q_p$. Next $\tilde \rho$ defines a representation
$\tilde \rho: G \rightarrow (D \otimes \mathbb Q_p)^\ast$, hence a representation of algebra
 $\tilde \rho : \mathbb Q_p[G] \rightarrow D \otimes \mathbb Q_p$, which is surjective by 
absolute irreducibility, and whose kernel is $\ker tr red (\tilde \rho)$ 
where $tr red \tilde \rho$ is the reduced trace of $\tilde \rho$, but as one sees by going up to $\mathbb C$,
is also $tr \rho$. Now the same argument applied to $\rho$ itself gives
also a surjective morphism $\mathbb Q_p \rightarrow M_n(\mathbb Q_p)$ with kernel $ker\  tr \rho$. Hence $M_n(\mathbb Q_p) \simeq D\otimes \mathbb Q_p$, QED.

---

PS: I think my presentation in the argument is in fact unnecessarily complicated, because
I stick to the language of representation, while everything would be much clearer in the language of pseudo-characters. Indeed, there are four representations
in the short argument above (over $\mathbb C$, over $\mathbb Q_p$, over a central simple algebra K, over  a central simple algebra over $K_{\mathcal P}$, but all those are incarnation 
of one single object, the pseudo-character $T: G \rightarrow \mathbb Q_p \subset \mathbb C$ defined by $T=tr \rho$. Now the proof of the lemma is simply that (1) $K$ which is defined as the field generated by $T(G)$ is by definition inside $\mathbb Q_p$ (2) Taylor-Rouquier's theorem:
Over a given field (here $\mathbb Q_p$), an absolutely irreducible pseudo-character has one and only one (we use the only one part here, which is the easy part of the result) realization
as the (reduced) trace of a representation over a central simple algebra. We apply this to the field $\mathbb Q_p$, giving us that our two realization, in $M_n(\mathbb Q _p)$ and in $D \otimes \mathbb Q_p$ have to be the same.

Comment: Thanks! I have a little difficulty in understanding the step (1) implies (2) : by $r_i$ is defined over $\mathbf{Q}_p$, you mean that it has a model over $\mathbf{Q}_p$ up to isomorphism, then why are the subrepresentations $\rho_{i,j}$ also defined over $\mathbf{Q}_p$? (sorry if this turns out to be obvious)

Comment: Dear François, I have added some details.


Comment: $\mathbf{Z}/3\mathbf{Z}$ has a faithful $2$-dimensional representation over $\mathbf{Q}_p$ for all primes $p$, but this is not true of the sub-representations which are only defined over $\mathbf{Q}_p(\zeta_3)$.

Comment: Dear Joël, thank you very much for the useful details. I should look for the theory of pseudo-characters. I agree that $\rho_{i,j}$ being defined over $\mathbf{Q}_p$ implies that $p$ splits in $D_{i,j}$. What I don't get yet is the following argument you seem to use at the end of (2) (correct me if I'm wrong) : if an $L$-valued representation $\rho$ decomposes as $\rho_1 \oplus \rho_2$ and if $\rho$ is realizable over a subfield $K \subset L$, then so are $\rho_1$ and $rho_2$. (This can be false, e.g. $G=\mathbf{Z}/4\mathbf{Z}$ embeds into $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{R})$ using $(0,-1;1,0)$.)

Comment: Ah, you guys are right, there is a mistake. I edit.

Comment: Pourquoi François, Joël et Rabelais sont-ils en train de discuter des maths en anglais ? 

Comment: J'ai du mal à comprendre l'ancien français de Rabelais. 